# Prove that for every idempotent element a belonging to $A$ (ie such that $a^2 = a$) and for every $b$ belonging to $A$ then $ab = ba$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence, idempotents

Let $A$ be a ring without nonzero nilpotent elements. Prove that for every idempotent element a belonging to $A$ (ie such that $a^2 = a$) and for every $b$ belonging to $A$ then $ab = ba$.

I know that proving that $ab=ba$ is equivalent to proving that $ab-ba=0$ but I try to use the hypothesis and arrive at $ab(1-a)=0$ where I cannot conclude anything because $A$ is not a domain of integrity.

Somebody could help me?

Comment: The statement is not true.

Comment: Hint: Consider the elements $ab-aba$ and $ba-aba$, try to show that given the hypotheses that they are both $0$.

Comment: Ok, I have it, and then, how I conclude ab=ba?

Comment: @Misimiausis  Then you have $ab-ba = (ab-aba)-(ba-aba) = 0-0 = 0$.

Comment: Evelia gon be proud

Comment: Yes, she was @YausetCabrera